# In MySql database, how to query on field without bothering about case of fields in Perl DBI

Tags: mysql, database, perl, dbi

I have below query in perl DBI -

```
$query = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM domain WHERE domainname = ? AND servicename = ?");
$query->execute( $domain, $service );
```

where the servicename can be case insensitive i.e if my existing service name is 'Storage' then it should fetch the result for 'storage' also.

I tried below code -

```
query = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM domain WHERE domainname = ? AND servicename = lower(?)");
$query->execute( $domain, $service );
```

But it is not working for servicename = 'storage'.

Any pointer where i have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also use `lower`function for the column value:

```
query = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM domain WHERE domainname = ? AND lower(servicename) = lower(?)");
$query->execute( $domain, $service );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ilike` function of Mysql 
it is case insensitive

```
query = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM domain WHERE domainname = ? AND servicename = ilike(?)"
);
```

$query->execute( $domain, $service );

`ilike` makes the comparison **case insensitive**.